# i have two geodata frames in geopandas that are not aligning

Tags: mapping, geopandas, projection

I am mapping my location history using Geopandas during a timeframe where I travelled from NYC (which I started working with and was able to map out) to Ithaca (upstate). My location history points show that I travelled to Ithaca but when I tried adding Ithaca's geodata file the location points and the map plot do not align.

I think there might be an issue with projection- but I don't know what exactly or how to fix it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgQli.png)

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can pinpoint where exactly things go wrong!

Answer (score 0):

You could start with checking the CRS of your geodata files. For example, if the file with your location history points is `history.shp`, then you can check it like this in Python:

```py
>>> import geopandas
>>> gdf = geopandas.read_file("history.shp")
>>> print(gdf.crs)
epsg:31467
```

Do the same with the map file. If the map has a different CRS, say `epsg:4326`, then you could transform the CRS of your history geodata frame to `epsg:4326` like this:

```py
>>> gdf.to_crs(epsg='4326', inplace=True)
```

Then you could try to plot both of your geo data frames on the same axes.